# Is there a way for me to automatically fill a forms text field with a session variable?

Tags: php, session

I'm coding a simple PHP game. So far I have all the mechanics working well. However, the user is already had to login on a previous page and has set a session variable for their username. I'd like that username session variable to automatically fill a username text field that this new page has.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>POKEMON FIGHT!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['attack'])) {
    $_POST['attack'] = false;
}

if(!isset($_POST['potion'])) {
    $_POST['potion'] = false;
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['potions'] = 3;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['userhp'] = 300;
    $_SESSION['aihp'] = 300;
    $_SESSION['specialmovepower'] = 10;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if($_POST['attack'] == "move 1") {
        $userhit = rand(1, 5);
        $aihit = rand(1, 5);
        $_SESSION['userhp'] = $_SESSION['userhp'] - $aihit;
        $_SESSION['aihp'] = $_SESSION['aihp'] - $userhit;

    } elseif (($_POST['potion'] == "potion") && ($_SESSION['potions'] >= 1)){

        if($_SESSION['userhp'] >= 75) {
            $_SESSION['userhp'] = 100;

        } else {
            $_SESSION['userhp'] = $_SESSION['userhp'] + 50;
        }
        $_SESSION['potions']--;

    } elseif ($_POST['attack'] == "move 2") {
        $userhit = rand(10, 15);
        $aihit = rand(10, 15);
        $_SESSION['userhp'] = $_SESSION['userhp'] - $aihit;
        $_SESSION['aihp'] = $_SESSION['aihp'] - $userhit;

    } elseif ($_POST['attack'] == "move 3") {
        $userhit = rand(20, 25);
        $aihit = rand(20, 25);
        $_SESSION['userhp'] = $_SESSION['userhp'] - $aihit;
        $_SESSION['aihp'] = $_SESSION['aihp'] - $userhit;

    } elseif ($_POST['attack'] == "move 4") {

        if($_SESSION['specialmovepower'] >1) {
        $userhit = rand(50, 40);
        $aihit = rand(50, 40);
        $_SESSION['userhp'] = $_SESSION['userhp'] - $aihit;
        $_SESSION['aihp'] = $_SESSION['aihp'] - $userhit;
        $_SESSION['specialmovepower'] = $_SESSION['specialmovepower'] - 2.5;

    } else {
        $error = "You do not have enough Special Move Power!<br /><br />";
    }
}

if ($_SESSION['userhp'] <=0) { $_SESSION['userhp'] = 0; }
if ($_SESSION['aihp'] <=0) { $_SESSION['aihp'] = 0; }

echo '<h2>Your turn '.htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']).'
<br></br>
<strong>Your health:</strong> '.$_SESSION['userhp'].'<br />
<strong>Enemy\'s health:</strong> '.$_SESSION['aihp'].'<br />
<strong>Potions left:</strong> '.$_SESSION['potions'].'<br />
<strong>Special Move Power Left:</strong> '.$_SESSION['specialmovepower'].'<br />';

if (($_SESSION['userhp'] <= 0) && ($_SESSION['aihp'] <= 0)) {
    echo '<br /><strong>You both died!</strong><br />
    <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">Play again</a>';
    unset($_SESSION['userhp']);
    unset($_SESSION['aihp']);
    unset($_SESSION['potions']);
    unset($_SESSION['specialmovepower']);
    unset($_SESSION['username']);

} elseif ($_SESSION['userhp'] <= 0) {
    echo '<br /><strong>You lose!</strong><br />
    <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">Play again</a>';
    unset($_SESSION['userhp']);
    unset($_SESSION['aihp']);
    unset($_SESSION['potions']);
    unset($_SESSION['specialmovepower']); 
    unset($_SESSION['username']);

} elseif ($_SESSION['aihp'] <= 0) {
    echo '<br /><strong>You win!</strong><br />
    <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">Play again</a>';
    unset($_SESSION['userhp']);
    unset($_SESSION['aihp']);
    unset($_SESSION['potions']);
    unset($_SESSION['specialmovepower']);
    unset($_SESSION['username']);

} else {
   echo '<form action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="attack" value="move 1" /><input type="submit" name="attack" value="move 2" /><input type="submit" name="attack" value="move 3" /><input type="submit" name="attack" value="move 4" />
    <input type="submit" name="potion" value="potion" /></form>';
    }   

} else {
    echo 'Are you sure you want to play?';
    echo '<form action="" method="POST">Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    If so press Play! <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Play!" /></form>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you're using cookies for session handling, your session_start() should come before any output/HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for the input tag. Write in the input tag `value="' .  $_SESSION["username"] . '"`

It set the default value for the input tag and add the session-value in the `""`.

[Look here for more informations about the input tag.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: I've done what you've suggested however it breaks most of the code. As well as not working unless i press play again which results in me entering a username anyway. Is there a way around that? Or better to just rewrite the code?

Comment: Replace the last echo of your code (with the input tag) with this:  echo '<form action="" method="POST">Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="'.$_SESSION["username"].' /><br /> If so press Play! <br /> <input type="submit" value="Play!" /></form>';

Comment: I'm still getting the same/similar errors. When you first load the page what happens is this [link](http://i.imgur.com/uRIXaiE.png) and once you click the play again this happens [link](http://i.imgur.com/iq2ln1B.png) it still messes with everything else which i'm not quite sure why. Would you know what could be causing the problem? I believe it has something to do with POST'ing the data when it doesn't need to in this section [link](http://i.imgur.com/ka3bJCb.png) but I've tried making that a session variable however it still results in the same problem and makes more.

Comment: Try to set the session_start() function befor any html-code. Your errors mean the values in the array not found. Also you can try to dump this array to check the values. You can use the function var_dump to dump a array.

Comment: It works well on the first go. After that it all breaks. What i believe the problem to be is that when it 'unset' the session variables it relies on going back to the part where you enter your username to then go back to the if statement relating posting username to set the session variables again for potions, health etc. I'm thinking maybe is there a variable similar to _Session but bellow it? so maybe just for this script so then it can keep username set in the box automatically but this lower level username is being reset each time? Also it doesn't seem to enter the username in to the input